# Check if inserted and deleted tables are identical in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I wrote a trigger to keep a history of updates in a table. It is working well. However, I noticed sometimes the table is updated with the same exact values. This effectively does not change the table but fires the trigger, resulting in duplicate rows in my history table.

To solve this, I'd like to only execute the body of my trigger when the `inserted` and `deleted` tables are not identical.

Here is my current trigger. It consists of a MERGE and an INSERT. If the `inserted` and `deleted` tables are identical, I don't want to MERGE nor INSERT:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yesterday date, @maxDate date
    SET @yesterday = DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE())
    SET @maxDate = '9999-12-31'

    MERGE dbo.tblHistory AS Target
    USING (SELECT * FROM inserted) AS Source 
       ON (Target.ID = Source.ID AND Target.EndDate = @maxDate)

    WHEN MATCHED AND Target.StartDate > @yesterday THEN
        DELETE

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET Target.EndDate = @yesterday
    ;

    --Insert updated row into History here
END
```

This seems to be the most human-readable and logical way to do it. However I'm not sure if it's the most effective.

Comment: Is this trigger `for update` only? Or does it handle updates, deletes, and inserts?

Comment: unrelated: `USING (SELECT * FROM inserted) AS Source` can be shortened to `USING Inserted AS Source`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance update only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check using except operator like below

```
  ;with cte
   as
   (SELECT * FROM inserted
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM deleted
    union all
   SELECT * FROM deleted
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM inserted
   )
select * from cte

if @@rowcount>0
begin
--rest of your query
end
```

Comment: But you will return result set to client? Isn't it? If yes, there is need some wrap around EXCEPT.

Comment: I am not 100% sure whether user is returning results to client or just doing some processing

Comment: I'm not returning the result set. Testing this solution at the moment. I need to make some minor changes though.

Comment: This code will work incorrect: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) x(a)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) x(a)`

Comment: @TheGameiswar, however I think better to use count(*) and variable

Comment: The original worked for me. Mind explaining why you update with the cte and union?

Comment: As Ruslan stated, if inserted has rows `1,2` and deleted has rows `1,3` my first example wouldn't work